# How can I most productively check for overlaps between ETF holdings?

Tags: discussion

Why was [How can I most productively check for overlaps between ETF holdings?](https://superuser.com/q/1528844/1036833) closed? I explained my attempt in point 1. How can I explain more if I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 4):

All you have explained is "I have some data I got from some random place on the internet" and nothing more.

You have not shown the actual data (preferably in a textual form) *on this site* and instead linked only to a Quora question that is only marginally less vague than your question. There is some implication that there is a larger dataset behind the table at the linked site, it may well be that anything you want to do requires access to more data than you have.

1. **Show us your data.** Linking to some other website is not showing us anything, put at least a sample of the data *here*. Links should [never be the only information in your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) irrespective of whether it is a question or an answer.
2. **Explain what that data is showing.** where does it come from? What is the relationship between it? Is this the complete data set or some end result table?
3. **Tell us what you are *trying to do with that data*.** We don't know what your goal is. What kind of calculation are you trying to perform? What formulae are involved?
4. **What is the end result you expect to see.**
5. **Don't expect other people to do all your work for you.** The question and answer format is a collaborative paradigm. You tell us about your problem and where you are stuck and we (hopfully) get you past a hurdle. We cannot go out, source all your data, do all your calculations, format your output and give you a nicely coded spreadsheet. That doesnt work here. **You have to help us to help you.**

Even if you have no experience whatsoever with Excel you should be able to provide that absolute bare minimum of input into your question.

As it stands your question is effectively "I found something on the internet, how do I do something?" If that link moves or goes dead then we would have absolutely no idea what your problem actually was. As it stands it is already nearly impossible to know what the actual problem.

Words are worth a thousand pictures, and more than a million links. Use your words.

Finally you ask for "other free more productive solutions?" (Presumably some other software that would do the task better than Excel.)

1. Asking for products that provide some solution is off topic here. We do not go out and do shopping for solutions.
2. You have not actually explained the problem in the first place to know what solution is not "productive".

---

For posterity the question in it's current form:

> #### How can I most productively check for overlaps between ETF holdings?
>
> For instance NASDAQ and S&P500 overlap as [listed in this Quora post dated May 11 2017](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-companies-in-the-NASDAQ-that-are-part-of-the-S-P-500).
>
> 1. After I copying and paste each ETF or index's Web page of holdings to Excel, how do I command Excel to check for overlaps?
> 2. Are there other free more productive solutions?